# Border radius proportions

Tags: html, css

```
#menu a {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 67px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Novecentosanswide-Book;
        font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
        text-transform:lowercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #81878b;
    border: none;
        padding: 4px 9px 9px 0px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
     background-color: #ff672a;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have this css code which basically just creates a rounded rectangle. It works fine but I want to make it a bit longer, so I increase the padding in the #menu a and what it does is it increases the size of the rectangle proportionaly to the right, so it looks out of place. What I want to do is just increase it's lenght, so that it would have about 9px on the right and the left of the link.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are concerned that the padding is "off center" and to the right.    This is because your padding definition is:

`padding: 4px 9px 9px 0px;`

Above is what you currently have.   Padding is defined as:

`padding: top right bottom left`

You can see above, you are setting the right side to 9px, but the left side to 0px.    If you want this to be proportional, make sure the right and left values are equal.

Comment: Wow, what a silly mistake by me :D And I was ransacking my brain a whole hour trying to figure out what's wrong.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I thought you need to make a bock with desired height and width with the text alignment with center always. So you can use like below,

```
a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Which aligns the text in the middle. Please check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/rYTm9/).

Comment: This wont work as I want it to, because the text in the link will differ by it's length. I want it to have a blank space of 9px despite the text length. Already figured it out, though. It was just me being scatterbrained.